# How to transfer the shader group node creation code to a class?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

I need to create a node that will hide unnecessary information from users and started to transfer material node creation code to the group(it creates the group by pressing the button on a panel) but I need to register it with an addon.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import NodeTree, Node, NodeSocket
 
class NODE_PT_MAINPANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom Node Group"
    bl_idname = "NODE_PT_MAINPANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'New Tab' 
 
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('node.test_operator')
 
 
def create_test_group(context, operator, group_name):

    bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True

    test_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(group_name, 'ShaderNodeTree')

    group_inputs = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_inputs.location = (-850,0)

    # Create group inputs
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Diffuse BM')
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Specular MM')
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Normal NM')
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Detail NM')

    # Create group outputs
    group_outputs = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    group_outputs.location = (300,0)
    test_group.outputs.new('NodeSocketShader','Surface')

    # Shader node
    node_shader = test_group.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
    node_shader.location = (0,300)

    # RGB nodes
    rgb_separate = test_group.nodes.new('ShaderNodeSeparateRGB')
    rgb_separate.location =(-860, -550)

    rgb_combine_node = test_group.nodes.new('ShaderNodeCombineRGB')
    rgb_combine_node.location = (-670, -500)

    # Create an invert node
    invert_spec = test_group.nodes.new('ShaderNodeInvert')
    invert_spec.location = (-330, 60)

    normal_map_node =  test_group.nodes.new('ShaderNodeNormalMap') # create normal map node
    normal_map_node.location = (-200, -260)

    link = test_group.links.new

    link(node_shader.outputs[0], group_outputs.inputs[0] )
    link(group_inputs.outputs[0], node_shader.inputs[0])
    link(group_inputs.outputs[1], invert_spec.inputs[1])
    link(invert_spec.outputs[0], node_shader.inputs[9])
    link(group_inputs.outputs[2], rgb_separate.inputs[0])

    return test_group
    
             
class NODE_OT_TEST(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Custom Shader Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.test_operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        custom_node_name = "MT Framework shader"
        my_group = create_test_group(self, context, custom_node_name)
        #test_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
        #test_node.node_tree = bpy.data.shader_node_groups[my_group.name]
        #test_node.use_custom_color = True
        #test_node.color = (0.5, 0.4, 0.3)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
            
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_TEST)
    
    
    
 
 
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_TEST)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I found a Blender example how to register a node but I have no clue how to combine them, also with bpy.types.ShaderNodeCustomGroup as a parent the node just lose all connections

````
import bpy
from nodeitems_utils import NodeItem, register_node_categories, unregister_node_categories
from nodeitems_builtins import ShaderNodeCategory

#class MTFrameworkShaderNode(bpy.types.ShaderNodeCustomGroup):
class MTFrameworkShaderNode(bpy.types.ShaderNode):
    bl_name='MTFramework RE5'
    bl_label='MTFramework RE5 Node' 
    
    my_string_prop: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    my_float_prop: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

    # === Optional Functions ===
    # Initialization function, called when a new node is created.
    # This is the most common place to create the sockets for a node, as shown below.
    # NOTE: this is not the same as the standard __init__ function in Python, which is
    #       a purely internal Python method and unknown to the node system!
    def init(self, context):
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', "Diffuse BM")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', "Specular MM")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', "Normal NM")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', "Detail NM")

        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketShader',"Surface")
        node_shader = self.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
    
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.template_image(self.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'], 'image') 

    # Copy function to initialize a copied node from an existing one.
    def copy(self, node):
        print("Copying from node ", node)

    # Free function to clean up on removal.
    def free(self):
        print("Removing node ", self, ", Goodbye!")

    # Additional buttons displayed on the node.
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.label(text="Node settings")
        layout.prop(self, "my_float_prop", text="Alpha Transparency")

    # Detail buttons in the sidebar.
    # If this function is not defined, the draw_buttons function is used instead
    def draw_buttons_ext(self, context, layout):
        layout.prop(self, "my_float_prop")
        # my_string_prop button will only be visible in the sidebar
        layout.prop(self, "my_string_prop")

    # Optional: custom label
    # Explicit user label overrides this, but here we can define a label dynamically
    def draw_label(self):
        return "MTFramework RE5 Node"

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MTFrameworkShaderNode)
    newcatlist = [ShaderNodeCategory("ALBAM", "Albam Nodes", items=[NodeItem("MTFrameworkShaderNode")])]
    register_node_categories("ALBAM_NODES", newcatlist)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MTFrameworkShaderNode)
    unregister_node_categories("ALBAM_NODES", newcatlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Comment: Custom nodes are not possible in the existing node_tree i.e. `ShaderNode`, `CompositorNode`, `TextureNode` and `GeometryNode`.

Comment: But I don't need a custom node, I need to register my shader node group with an addon properly, not by a function running by the operator from a UI panel.